# Manipulating DOM element added by third-party script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**The situation:**

An external third-party script is loaded that adds some stuff to the DOM.

**The goal:**

As soon as that stuff is added to the DOM, I want to manipulate its content with a bit of jQuery.

To make sure this new DOM element exists before manipulating it, I can do something like this:

```
var updateText, target;

updateText = function() {
    target = $('#targetElement');
    if(target.length) {
        target.text('Updated!');
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(updateText, 500);
    }
};

updateText();
```

It just seems kind of hideous. Is there any better way of dealing with this sort of dependency?

**Relevant constraints:**

- The third-party script has no exposed API.
- In order to work, this particularly script apparently *must* be loaded via a `<script>` element with a specific URL in the `src` attribute. So loading the script by passing to [$script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/) doesn't work.
- When it runs, it also loads its own bundle of external dependencies in turn. Even if I can check that the initial script is loaded before firing off my own code, I don't know that I can check against these other external scripts.

Comment: Since your code is working and you're looking for a better/cleaner implementation, it might be better to post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does that third-party script use async code?

Comment: @Oriol It's a bit ugly and I've only dug through it a little. I see several dependencies getting requested via `script` elements appended to the `head`.

Comment: @mutus You can try using a `load` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the DOMSubtreeModified event. Here is an example:

```js
$("#a").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
    $("span").css("background", "blue");
});


$("#add").click(function() {a
    $("#a").append("<span>hey there</span><br>");
});
```

```css
div {
    background-color: black;
}

span {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
</div>

<button id="add">Add to Div</button>
```

Comment: This works (in a manner), but `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated. I gather for very good (performance-related) reasons.